# hive order by 1 asc results in incorrect oder

Tags: hadoop, hive

The query:

`SELECT DISTINCT   seg from mytable ORDER BY 1 ASC` results in

```
+-------+--+
|  seg  |
+-------+--+
| NONE  |
| AFS   |
+-------+--+
```

where as `SELECT DISTINCT   seg from mytable ORDER BY seg ASC` results in

```
+-------+--+
|  seg  |
+-------+--+
| AFS   |
| NONE  |
+-------+--+
```

Is referring to the columns by position in the ORDER BY not supported by Hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by position is supported since Hive 0.11 but only from Hive 2.2.0 it is turned on by default.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

> **hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias**
>   Default Value: false
>   Added In: Hive 0.11.0 with HIVE-581
>   Deprecated In: Hive 2.2.0 with HIVE-15797
>   Whether to enable using Column Position Alias in GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses of queries (deprecated as of Hive 2.2.0; use hive.groupby.position.alias and hive.orderby.position.alias instead).

---

> **hive.orderby.position.alias**
>   Default Value: true
>   Added In: Hive 2.2.0 with HIVE-15797
>   Whether to enable using Column Position Alias in ORDER BY.

Comment: i'm using CDH5 quickstart vm 5.10.0-0.

I added this config in /etc/hive/conf/hive-stie.xml
  <property>
    <name>hive.orderby.position.alias</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

After adding it, I restarted hive service by:

service hive-server2 stop
service hive-metastore stop.

Followed by start. 

But I still see the same issue. What could be the reason?

Comment: In order to test it, `set hive.orderby.position.alias=true;` would be enough.

Comment: Thanks it worked when I set this property in hive /beeline console.